# How to connect several devices on a gatt server using BLE?

Tags: android, node.js, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I made a connection between an Android device and a gatt server using bleno module from Nodejs in a RaspberryPi. 
I'm sending some datas with my phone and in the meanwhile I want to connect an other device to the gatt server. However when I want to do this, I cannot see the RaspberryPi ie the gatt server with this second device. I'm new to ble so I was wondering if my phone has an issue or it's the technology that is actually like that. If not , is there a way to connect several devices to a same gatt server ?